# Как вернуть переменную int из функции в dll на C++ обратно в приложение на C#?

Tags: c#, c++, dll

Имеется приложение на C#, которое должно передать в dll массив структур. Результат обработки массива функция dll должна возвратить в виде переменной int. Поиск показал, что направление работы - это использование технологии PInvoke (см. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/dotnet/calling-native-functions-from-managed-code?view=msvc-170). C этим я еще буду разбираться. Сейчас столкнулся с проблемой корректного написания кода самой dll. Все примеры, что мне удалось найти, предлагают такой синтаксис записи: return a, где a - некоторая переменная. Visual Studio же предлагает автоматически вариант кода, который пока что распознается компилятором как ошибочный. Поиск по коду ошибки (E0029 - "Требуется выражение") ничего толком не дал. Вопрос - как корректно задать последний оператор функции, возвращающий переменную?

Привожу код библиотеки.
Точка входа:

```
// dllmain.cpp : Определяет точку входа для приложения DLL.
#include "pch.h"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Заголовочный файл:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef PACKINGDLL_EXPORTS
#define PACKINGDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define PACKINGTDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

typedef struct _PACKAGINGDATA
{
    int Lx;
    int Ly;
    int Lz;
    double dbl_Mass;
    bool Up;
} PACKAGINGDATA;

extern "C" PACKINGDLL_API int analysis(int int_Number, PACKAGINGDATA * sPD_Packaging_data);
```

Определение функции:

```
PACKINGDLL_API int analysis(int int_Number, PACKAGINGDATA* sPD_Packaging_data)
{
    return PACKINGDLL_API int();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Протестировал библиотеку с записью:

```
return a;
```

Для версии библиотеки и приложения C# х86 работает, осталось добиться, чтобы работало и для х64.